# Как сложить числа в двух таблицах?

Tags: sql

Есть две таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE [ostatky] (
  [id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  [d] INTEGER, 
  [m] VARCHAR(20), 
  [y] INTEGER, 
  [point] VARCHAR(80), 
  [predprijatie] VARCHAR(80), 
  [ostatok] CURRENCY);

CREATE TABLE [main] (
  [id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  [d] INTEGER, 
  [m] VARCHAR(20), 
  [y] INTEGER, 
  [point] VARCHAR(80), 
  [predprijatie] VARCHAR(80), 
  [prihod] CURRENCY, 
  [rashod] CURRENCY);
```

Надо получить результат сложения `[ostatok]` первой таблицы и `[prihod]` второй таблицы и от этого отнять `[rashod]` второй таблицы. Как то так:   `SUM(ostatok)+SUM(prihod)-SUM(rashod)`.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Соединять таблицы, похоже, нужно по предприятию и, возможно, еще по пункту, если знать, что это такое, но вряд ли по id. :-) 
А можно вообще ничего не соединять:

```
select SUM(prihod) - SUM(rashod) + (select sum(ostatok) from ostatky)
from main
```

Answer (score 2):

Только мне непонятно что там с квадратными скобками (в каких случаях писать, а в каких нет), но смысл такой:

```
select
    ID, SUM(o.ostatok)+SUM(m.prihod)-SUM(m.rashod)
from [ostatky] o
left join [main] m on (m.[id] = o.[id])
```

Comment: квадратные скобки - это аналог двойных кавычек в некоторых диалектах SQL (например, в T-SQL)